# How is cross_val_score calculated in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is it mean square error?  The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics) doesn't give much detail.

Comment: see: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L36

Comment: It depends on the type of problem. It differs for classification and regression tasks.

Comment: Also `cross_val_score` provides a `scoring` parameter, which can take user defined scoring method. If not specified, then the default scoring of the estimator is used.

Comment: Look here for more details : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, the score computed at each CV iteration is the `score` method of the estimator.

In other words, it does whatever the `score` method of your model does (or calls the provided scoring function); `cross_val_score` is just responsible for doing the cross-validation, not for defining what a "score" actually is.